# display only date from gridview to textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access-2007

i want to display only date into textbox from gridview
It displays as 11/03/2013 12:00:00 AM
but i want only date 11/03/2013
i database it is stored on date

i tried to modify my code as

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="reg_dt" Visible="False">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server"
                                            Text ='<%# Bind("reg_dt" ,"{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

but it displays same as first format
what changes should i do to display only date
plz help me

I m using datepicker to select date into textbox

Answer (score 2):

Use `{0:dd-MM-yyyy}`

`Text ='<%# Bind("reg_dt" ,"{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>'`

and html encoding to false.

### Example

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="PostalCode" htmlencode="false" headertext="ZIP Code"/>
```

Reference :- 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: from where to set html encoding to false i didnt get it

Comment: I didn't add this. Shekhar edited my answer. I would welcome it if he could clarify his edit.

Comment: @shekhar from where should i set html encoding to false

Comment: @shekhar Its for the boundfields i m using templateFields it does not take htmlencode property

Answer (score 2):

Set this property in ur gridview template fie

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" Text ='<%# Bind("reg_dt" ,"{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

or try this........
In aspx page ..........

```
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" Text='<%#  ConvertDate(Eval("   public string ConvertDate(object pobjDate, string pstrDateFormat)
    {
        if (pobjDate == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pobjDate.ToString()))
            return String.Empty;
        else
            return Convert.ToDateTime(pobjDate).ToString(pstrDateFormat);
    }"), "dd-MMM-yyyy") %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

in cs page........

```
   public string ConvertDate(object pobjDate, string pstrDateFormat)
        {
            if (pobjDate == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pobjDate.ToString()))
                return String.Empty;
            else
                return Convert.ToDateTime(pobjDate).ToString(pstrDateFormat);
        }
```

Comment: You are missing the closing `)` for the bind and closing `'` for the text property.

Comment: @chetanSanghai : i tried ur ans but its not working i dont know why?

Comment: @dev : try the ans which i posted below

Comment: @chetanSanghai i m trying i will let u know

Comment: @chetanSanghai it showed me error  Error   The name 'ConvertDate' does not exist in the current contex